# Why is my Excel file empty after writing content to cells using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Tags: excel, office365, interop

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to write an Excel file. The code below is not working:

```
var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
var worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "sheet1";

worksheet.Cells[1,1] = "top left";
worksheet.Cells[1,2] = "top right";
worksheet.Cells[2,1] = "bottom left";
worksheet.Cells[2,2] = "bottom right";

workbook.SaveAs("temp.xlsx");
workbook.Close();
excel.Quit();
```

It produces an Excel file but it is empty. I'm expecting to see the text "top left", "top right",... in the first 2 by 2 cells. But I see nothing.

Why is it not writing content to my worksheet?

You can find my code at github: https://github.com/gibran-shah/Image2Excel

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link might help you: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm
According to the link above, try using: 
var worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.get_Item(1);

To troubleshoot further, I would choose some other name for the sheet, and check that the name is actually being set by opening the workbook and observing the name in the sheet's tab.  This would ensure you are indeed adding data to the sheet that you think you are.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Brinky. I don't get any further with get_Item(1), or any of the variations of the code at that link. Setting the name of the sheet works (I get the name I specified) but still no content in the cells.